# Edit and Delete buttons are not working in form how to fix it

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code is incorrect for edit button when click on edit button it has to show the data of person which we clicked, and delete button also has to delete the selected person's data can't solve this issue buttons are not working properly give some advice how to fix it.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
              <title>Wizard form</title>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <link href="./css/form.css" rel="stylesheet">
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min
.css"integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
                     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

//css

```
.nav-item{width:160px;text-align: center;}
h2 {text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: bold}
li a :hover{}
.tab-content{display: none;}
.tab-content.active{display: block}
.next{padding:  5px 10px;border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;}
.prev{padding:  5px 10px;border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;}
.next:hover{background-color: #ccc}
.prev:hover{background-color: #ccc}
.wrap{padding:200px 30px 0 30px;}
table{width:100%}
tr{width:100%;}
tr th{width:8%; text-align:center; font-size:12px; border-bottom: 1px solid grey }
tr td{width:8%; text-align:center; font-size:12px; }
```

java script jquery started

```
            <script> // variables used
              var tab_id;
              var id=0;
              var fnm;
              var lnm;
              var gen;
              var mail;
              var num;
              var dob;
              var sport;
              var about;
              var tcn;
              var target;
              var edit;
        var count;
              $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".next").click(function () { //click function for next button
                  count = $(this).attr('data-tab');
                  show_form(count);
                  fnm = $("#fname").val();
                  lnm = $("#lname").val();
                  gen = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
                  mail = $("#mail").val();
                  num = $("#number").val();
                  dob = $("#dob").val();

                });
                $(".prev").click(function () {
                  count = $(this).attr('data-tab');
                  show_form(count);
                });

                function show_form(count) {
                  tab_id = count;
                  $('li a').removeClass('active');
                  $('.tab-content').hide();
                  $("." + tab_id).addClass("active");
                  $("#" + tab_id).show();

                }


                function reset() {
                  $("#fname").val("");
                  $("#lname").val("");
                  $("input[name='gender']").prop("checked", false);
                  $("#mail").val(" ");
                  $("#number").val(" ");
                  $("#dob").val("");
                  $("#sport").val("");
                  $("#about").val("");
                  $("#tc").prop("checked", false);
                  console.log(id, fnm, lnm, gen, mail, num, dob, sport, about, tcn);
                }

                $("#sbmt").click(function () {
                  if ($('#tc').is(":checked")) {
                    tcn = "agree";
                  } else {
                    tcn = "disagree";
                  }
                  sport = $("#sport").val();
                  about = $("#about").val();
                  tab_data();
                  reset();
                });
                  function tab_data() {
                    id++;
                    var data_dlt = "<button class='next delete'>delete</button>";
                    var data_edt = "<a class='edit next' data-tab='tab1'>edit</a>";
                    $("table").append("<tr>" + "<td id='uid'>" + id + "</td>" + "<td>" + fnm + "</td>" + "<td>" + lnm + "</td>" +
                      "<td>" + gen + "</td>" + "<td>" + mail + "</td>" + "<td>" + num + "</td>" + "<td>" + dob + "</td>" +
                      "<td>" + sport + "</td>" + "<td>" + about + "</td>" + "<td>" + tcn + "</td>" + "<td>" + data_edt + "</td>" + "<td>" + data_dlt + "</td>" + "</tr>");


                    $(".edit").click(function () {
                      count = $(this).attr('data-tab');
                      show_form(count);
                      edit = ($(this).index());
                      console.log(edit);
                      $("#fname").val(fnm);
                      $("#lname").val(lnm);
                      $("input[name='gender']").prop("checked", false);
                      $("#mail").val(mail);
                      $("#number").val(num);
                      $("#dob").val(dob);
                      $("#sport").val(sport);
                      $("#about").val(about);
                      $("#tc").prop("checked", false);
                      console.log(id, fnm, lnm, gen, mail, num, dob, sport, about, tcn);
                    });

                    $("#del").click(function () {
                      target = $("td button .delete").index(this);
                      console.log(target);

                    });
                  }
              })



            </script>
```

HTML with Bootstrap

```
        <div class="container clearfix" style="padding:30px 20%;">
          <h2>Wizard Form</h2>
          <br>
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link tab1 active" data-tab="tab1"  >STEP 1</a>
            </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link tab2" data-tab="tab2" >STEP 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link tab3" data-tab="tab3">STEP 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Tab panes -->

        <div id="tab1" class=" tab-pane tab-content active"><br>
            <form>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">First Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter first name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="lname" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Last Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Enter last name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-3 pt-0">Gender:</legend>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
              </fieldset>
                <div>
                 <a data-tab="tab2"   class="next" >SAVE & NEXT</a>
             </div>
            </form>

        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane tab-content"><br>
            <form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="mail" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Email:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input id="mail" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="number" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Contact No:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input id="number" type="text" placeholder="Enter contact number" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="dob" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Date Of Birth: </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input  id="dob" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top:20px;">
                <a data-tab="tab1" class=" prev">PREVIOUS</a>
                <a data-tab="tab3"  class=" next">SAVE & NEXT</a>
                </div>
         </form>

        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane tab-content"><br>
            <form action="#" methos="post">
            <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="sport" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> Favourite Sport</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select id="sport" class="form-control">
                <option selected></option>
            <option >Cricket</option>
            <option >Tennis</option>
            <option >Soccer</option>
            <option >Hockey</option>
            <option >Wrestling</option>
            </select>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="about" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">About Yourself</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="about" rows="1"></textarea>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="tc" value="agree">
                        <label for="tc" class=" col-form-label" >I agree to <a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a data-tab="tab2 " class="prev">PREVIOUS</a>
                 <a class="next " data-tab="tab1" id="sbmt" >submit</a>
            </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Contact no </th>
                <th>DOB</th>
                <th>sports</th>
                <th>About </th>
                <th>T&C</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have not added id = 'del' to the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```html
var data_dlt = "<button class='next delete'>delete</button>";
```

With

```html
var data_dlt = "<button class='next delete' id='del' name='del'>delete</button>";
```

Comment: but how it get the id which row i want to delete.